# Unable to Add shockwave flash object to windows form in word add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, shockwave, axshockwaveflash

I have Word add-in contains a windows from that contains a shockwave flash object.

I'm using vs2010, .net3.5.

The problem is that i'm unable to add shockwave flash object to windows form in word add-in, but I can add it in normal form in normal windows form application, why?

Comment: Its not clear what your question is.  Are you trying to develop a Word Add-on tat contains a shockwave flash object?

Comment: yes, the Word add-in contains a windows from that contains a shockwave flash object, i'm using vs2010, .net3.5

Comment: You need to update your question with the relevant facts you just shared.

Comment: okay, question updated.